# A Regular Map Has Finitely Many Ramification Points

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C,D$ be nonsingular projective curves, $f \colon C \to D$ nonconstant, $K = k(C), L = k(D)$, $d = \text{deg }f = [K:L]$, and of course $k$ algebraically closed. Furthermore let's suppose that $K:L$ is separable. I'm trying to understand why it is that $|f^{-1}(p)| = d$ for all but finitely many $p \in D$. Basically, I want to show that if $f$ is unramified at $p$ then it's unramified on an open neighborhood of $p$, then show that if $K:L$ is separable then $f$ is unramified at at least one such point.

I have an argument in progress but there's something I don't quite understand. If $p \in D$ then we can let $q_1,\ldots,q_k$ be the preimages under $f$, find some $g$ that has distinct values at all $q_i$, then let $m$ be the minimal polynomial of $g$ over $L$ (which has coefficients in $B$, for algebraic reasons). Because $m$ has coefficients in $B$ we can form $m_0$ where we just evaluate all of its coefficients at $p$. Then $m_0$ has at least $k$ distinct roots (namely, $g(q_i)$). Obviously $\partial m = \partial m_0 \leq d$ as well. So if $p$ is ramified, then the roots of $m$ - and $m_0$ - are distinct hence $\Delta m_0 = \Delta m(p) \neq 0$. This is an algebraic condition so there is a neighborhood on which $\Delta m$ is nonzero, etc.

However, there's something I'm missing. I don't know that it makes sense to say that $\Delta m(p') \neq 0$ means that $f$ is unramified at $p'$. After all, $m$ doesn't appear to have a lot to do with $p'$. But $m$ can't change from point to point because then it's not an algebraic condition anymore - it's a logical condition. There should be something that says that if some fixed $m_0$ has $d$ distinct roots then $p$ has $d$ distinct pullbacks, but I can't find it. Can someone point me in the right direction?